Add dropdown to Excel linked to sql table that will show related value in next cell?
I know it's a horrible title.
I added a dropdown to an Excel cell that's based on Employee.EmpId, so that when the end-user clicks on the dropdown he will see something like this, which is fine since the user input is the EmpId:

But I'd like to somehow display the Name when the user selects the EmpId. For example, the dropdown is in cell B2 and when I select 0001 then cell B3 will show Joe Smith. That way the end-user knows what employee he selected.
The query where the dropdown list comes from already has the name.
Is there a relatively easy way of doing this?


yes, one relatively simple way is to use a lookup formula.
